# IE8 loads images and css from server and does not save them in cache, how to force IE takes images from the cache?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, http, caching, mozilla

I created web site, JSP, runs on Tomcat.

IE8 does not load images from cache, although I try that and it loaded from cache in mozilla.
Cache is not disabled in my IE8.

Tomcat log for mozilla produces 304 status code:
"GET /petelina/images/main/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -

Tomcat log for IE8 is always 200:
super [26/Nov/2010:20:10:07 +0200] "GET /petelina/images/main/bg_left_column.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1394

res.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000L); - does not help, if I set it in filter for static content.

How to force IE8 work with cache?????!!!!

Answer (score 0):

First check your page with http://validator.w3.org

Which Document Mode is IE8 defaulting to? Looks like Quirks which may lead to non-caching problem.